# How Does One Extend the Drawing Manager?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Drawing Manager for Google Maps Javascript Library v3 Drawing Library provides 6 tools, none of which is an arc.  So I'd like to add an arc tool for my users.  However I see no documentation on how one might go about doing this.

I'd like it to work much like the circle tool.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 'Polyline', as employed in Google-Earth.
But, this technique may not perfect when users zoom-in/out view level,understand?

Comment: With, for example, the circle tool, one can dynamically resize the circle and it will animate the change in size of the circle.  What I'm hearing you say is that in order to accomplish this effect, there is some way of capturing events that would normally go to one of the points on the polyline and, instead of changing just that point on the polyline, it would change some attribute of the arc.  Is the right?  (Yes, I understand that polylines won't produce a true circle but instead part of a regular polygon.)